# CSS flexbox 3 columns desktop to 2 columns tablet with re-ordering of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to solve a problem I have with flexbox but can't figure out how.

Here is what I want on desktop

[image: desktop version]

And here is what I want on tablet

[image: tablet version]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.premiumContent,
.aside1Content,
.aside2Content {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.premiumContent {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.aside1Content {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
}
.aside2Content {
  order: 3;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="premiumContent">premium</div>
  <div class="aside1Content">aside 1</div>
  <div class="aside2Content">aside 2</div>
</div>
```

I did a codepen if you want to play around:

https://codepen.io/martinratinaud/pen/rjBbLz?editors=1100

**EDIT: here is the solved example with the right media query https://codepen.io/martinratinaud/pen/QdLRNO**

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note Michael_B's solution is the proper `flexbox` one. This one uses `position:absolute` and `margin-right` for positioning on mobile devices, for the special case when the height of the parent cannot be pre-determined or hard-coded in CSS.

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.premiumContent {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 3em;
}
.aside1Content {
  order: -1;
  background-color: blue;
}
.aside2Content {
  background-color: green;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: relative;
  }
  .wrapper > * {
    padding: .5em;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .wrapper .premiumContent {
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    order: 3;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    align-self: initial;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .aside1Content {
    order: initial;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="premiumContent">premium</div>
  <div class="aside1Content">aside 1</div>
  <div class="aside2Content">aside 2</div>
</div>
```

Fully prefixed CSS:

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
     -moz-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.premiumContent {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 3em;
}
.aside1Content {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
  -webkit-order: -1;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0;
      -ms-flex-order: -1;
          order: -1;
  background-color: blue;
}
.aside2Content {
  background-color: green;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
       -moz-box-orient: vertical;
       -moz-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
       -moz-box-align: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
            align-items: stretch;
    position: relative;
  }
  .wrapper > * {
    padding: .5em;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
       -moz-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .wrapper .premiumContent {
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
    -webkit-order: 3;
       -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;
        -ms-flex-order: 3;
            order: 3;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
       -moz-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex-positive: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-align-self: initial;
        -ms-flex-item-align: initial;
                -ms-grid-row-align: initial;
            align-self: initial;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .aside1Content {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: NaN;
    -webkit-order: initial;
       -moz-box-ordinal-group: NaN;
        -ms-flex-order: initial;
            order: initial;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Being able to wrap flex items in a column container *without a fixed height* is definitely a common need. It's good you're tackling this problem.

Comment: @Michael_B I thought flexbox is the answer to every layout need. Apparently, I was wrong. :) Thank you. In production I suppose I'd solve this by moving `aside1` and `aside2` inside a wrapper with [`enquire.js`](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll pick your solution as I can't have predefined height for my elements

Comment: Please note I tested it some more and there was a problem with `overflow` on small size. I fixed it, you should get the new code from answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query for the mobile layout:

```
@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .premiumContent, .aside1Content, .aside2Content {
    width: 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  .premiumContent {
    order: 4;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKbOZm?editors=1100)

Comment: Pretty sweet. Is there a solution without hard-coded height? And also, why is it this doesn't work with `order:3` for `.premiumContent` on column? I find this very strange. Any resource would be appreciated.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, a fixed height is needed in a column-direction container so that flex items know where to wrap. Without a fixed height, the column cannot break and will simply expand the container as it grows.

Comment: I used `order: 4` because `order: 3` was already used in the desktop layout.

Comment: I know a fixed height is needed for wrapping. Was just trying to figure out a non-js solution for allowing this layout to scale in height (using flexbox, without need of `position:absolute`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer but unfortunately, I don't know the height of my elements and thus can't use it on the wrapper. Especially, the `premium` div will receive th more text and thus will be bigger than the other ones